# VB.NET Else block

Tags: vb.net

I have the following:

```
   ... Else row("Deg") = txtEditOtherDegree.Text
```

How do I do an Else block as I need to add more to the Else part

Comment: Not sure about VB.NET, but with VBA/VB6 you can add your code on a newline after `Else` (and successive lines on with newlines between) so long as you end the `If` block with `End If`. Also, you can separate successive 'lines' with `:`. i.e. `...Else a = b: c = d: e = f`, but this can be harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put it on a separate line, and use `End If`:

```
If ... Then
  ...
Else
  row("Deg") = txtEditOtherDegree.Text
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need multiple clauses like this:

```
If ... Then
    ' Statements
ElseIf ... Then
    ' More Statements
ElseIf ... Then
    ' Other Statements
Else
    ' Final Statements
End If
```

Comment: Use ElseIF, not Else IF.  Else If requires separate, matching End If statement.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien: You are correct. I too used to `C#` where the keywords are separated.